# Минималистичный поиск по спискам с дальнейшим его определением

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим есть два списка:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

И значение:

```
item = 3
```

Нужно определить в каком списке находится это значение и отправить этот список дальше в метод (напр. `any_method(specific_list=...)`)

P.s. Вроде вопрос простой, но получается километровый код, интересно посмотреть на решение со стороны

Comment: `list_1 if item in list_1 else list_2` что ли?

Comment: @andreymal, как же лаконично в одну строку, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если списков будет много, то можно сделать так:

```
arr = [
    [7, 11, 15],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
]
item = 3

any_method(list(filter(lambda obj: item in obj, arr))[0])
```

правда все равно надо или в исключения заворачивать или учитывать, что ни одного списка может быть не найдено

или так:

```
any_method(next(filter(lambda obj: item in obj, arr), []))
```

тут как раз учитывается ситуация, когда ничего не будет найдено и тогда будет возвращен пустой список

Answer (score 1):

```
if item in list_1:
    any_method(specific_list=list_1))
elif item in list_2:
    any_method(specific_list=list_2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
any_method(specific_list=list_1 if item in list_1 else list_2)
```